# How I join my virtual machine into virtual domain using VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a laptop on which window 7 is installed and I also installed VirtualBox. In virtual box I made a small network, which consists of window server 2003 domain and XP and they both ping each other.

But now the problem is that I want the XP machine to join the domain hosted by the virtual server.

How can I do that?

Comment: As long as the virtual machines are on a properly functioning network, virtualization makes absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the XP machine to join the Server 2003 domain the server must be online at the same time as the XP machine.  So as long as you have enough resources to run both virtual machines simultaneously and you have properly created an Active Directory Domain on the Server 2003, then you can easily join the XP machine to the domain using Domain Admin credentials.

Be sure also, that you have installed DNS on the Server 2003 and that the XP Machine's DNS settings point ONLY to the Server 2003's IP address.

Further details on how to install AD on Server 2003:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324753

Further details on how to join the workstation are here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456990.aspx

Comment: Dear Jeffrey I have core i3 laptop which have the capability to run both machine simultaneously and also the AD and DNS is properly installed and they perform correct  function but still the problem exist.

Comment: Dear Jeffrey I have core i3 laptop which have the capability to run both machine simultaneously and also the AD and DNS is properly installed and they perform correct  function but still the problem exist.Moreover what you mean from the "Domain Admin credentials."I just use the common method which is go to Xp then My Computer properties,and Computer name and the Change and give the Domain name in the required place